# Get Datatable cell value in specific type

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have DataTable1 with data.
For example I have column

```
                idColumn = new DataColumn("MInvPrice", typeof(double));
```

and when I take value

```
        foreach (DataRow Row in MainTable.Rows)
        {
            double MInvPrice = Row["MInvPrice"];
        }
```

I'm getting exception, and have to write

```
            double MInvPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Row["MInvPrice"]);
```

So why I getting Object value, if type of this value is double? Can I get value in double without Convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rows property of the DataTable is an object of type DataRowCollection. That implements the non-generic ICollection interface, which means that the compiler can't infer the type of row beyond just object.
So you need to parse it wrt to your requirement. Anyway you can use :

```
var MInvPrice = Row["MInvPrice"];
```